# Extracting the latest file names from a path

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA Excel code which return file name from the paths(i will mention them).

In an excel file one of the column will have the files names (eg:- lgd_00,lgf_01) and these files will be in the paths(5 or 6 paths) which i will mention. The code should search the file name in path and extract the latest file name and copy beside it .

for example in a1 to a20 there are file names. consider "a1" has "lgd_00" but in the path i mentioned tere will be "lgd_00" file and after update it became  "lgd_01". Here "lgd_01" is the latest file so, the code should extract the "lgd_01"  and copy the it beside column(b1) of "lgd_00" in excel. if the "lgd_00" is latest file then it should copy it.

maybe the attached will help.

Appreciate your help on this.

Thank you

```
Sub LatestFileWithName()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String
Dim varDate As Variant
Dim strFind As String

Dim r As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


strPath = ""

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)


For r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

    If ws.Range("A" & r).Value = Left(objectFile, 20) Then

       strFind = ws.Range("A" & r).Value

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If InStr(1, objFile.Name, strFind, vbTextCompare) Then
If objFile.DateLastModified > varDate Then
strName = objFile.Name
varDate = objFile.DateLastModified

If Len(strName) = 0 Then
strName = "None found"
Else
strName = strName & " - is latest file - " & varDate
End If

  ws.Range("B" & r).Value = strName
                r = r + 1

End If
End If




  Next 'objFile
     End If
Next r

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite make out what you want but I programmed something that should be near. Please try it.

```
Sub LatestFileWithName()

    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim ItemName As String
    Dim Fn As String                            ' File name
    Dim Latest As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim R As Long

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then                      ' if OK is pressed
            SourceFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If SourceFolder <> "" Then                  ' a folder was chosen
        Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With Ws
            For R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
                ' read the file name from Sheet1!A:A
                '  this name has no path and no extension (like "lgh_00")
                ItemName = Trim(.Cells(R, "A").Value)
                If Len(ItemName) Then           ' skip if blank
                    Latest = ""
                    ItemName = Split(ItemName, "_")(0)

                    ' search for all items in the folder that have the same name
                    Fn = Dir(SourceFolder & "\" & ItemName & "*")
                    Do While Len(Fn) > 0
                        ' remember the largest one (e.g. 2 is larger than 1)
                        If Fn > Latest Then Latest = Fn
                        Fn = Dir
                    Loop

                    Sp = Split(Latest, ".")     ' remove the extension
                    If UBound(Sp) Then ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1)
                    .Cells(R, "B").Value = Join(Sp, ".")
                End If
            Next R
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

In Sheet1!A:A this macro expects file names like "lgd_00". The underscore is used in the code. There should be no extension and no path. When the macro starts it takes you to Windows Explorer's FolderPicker where you select a folder. Thereafter the macro will find the latest version of each file in A:A and write the name in B:B.